# 'tikz' style arrow tips missing when using tikz-cd crossing over

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have been using tikz-cd to create commutative diagrams. I just upgraded to version 0.9b from 0.3c and now there is a problem with the arrow tips. I like to use the 'tikz' solid tips. The following diagram is fine:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\title{}
\date{}  
\tikzset{
   commutative diagrams/.cd,
   diagrams={>=latex}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=scriptsize, column sep=scriptsize]
 & f^* E_V \arrow[dl] \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd] & & E_V \arrow[dl] \arrow[dd] \\ 
 f^* E \arrow[rr, crossing over] \arrow[dd] & & E \\ 
 & U \arrow[dl] \arrow[rr] & & V \arrow[dl] \\ 
 M \arrow[rr] & & N \arrow[uu, crossing over, leftarrow]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

and gives the following output:

[image: Normal behaviour]

However, if I change to solid tips (which take up less room and look better on the rather larger diagram I am really building) by adding an arrow style specification to the tikzset:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\title{}
\date{}  
\tikzset{
   commutative diagrams/.cd,
   arrow style=tikz,
   diagrams={>=latex}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=scriptsize, column sep=scriptsize]
 & f^* E_V \arrow[dl] \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd] & & E_V \arrow[dl] \arrow[dd] \\ 
 f^* E \arrow[rr, crossing over] \arrow[dd] & & E \\ 
 & U \arrow[dl] \arrow[rr] & & V \arrow[dl] \\ 
 M \arrow[rr] & & N \arrow[uu, crossing over, leftarrow]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I now get the following output in which the tips are missing from all lines that use the 'crossing over' feature PLUS the two diagonals from U and V and the horizontal from M to N:

[image: Arrow tips missing on crossing over lines]

This behaviour was not exhibited in v.0.3c. Any ideas how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the `crossing over` style.  The following seems to fix it:

[image: Sample ouptut]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
   commutative diagrams/.cd,
   arrow style=tikz,
   diagrams={>=latex}}
\tikzcdset{  crossing over/.style={
    /tikz/preaction={
      /tikz/draw,
      /tikz/color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/background color},
      /tikz/arrows=-,
      /tikz/line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative
      diagrams/crossing over clearance}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=scriptsize, column sep=scriptsize]
 & f^* E_V \arrow[dl] \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd] & & E_V \arrow[dl] \arrow[dd] \\ 
 f^* E \arrow[dd] \arrow[rr,crossing over]  & & E \\ 
 & U \arrow[dl] \arrow[rr] & & V \arrow[dl] \\ 
 M \arrow[rr] & & N \arrow[uu, crossing over, leftarrow]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The original style is

```
  crossing over/.style={
    /tikz/preaction={
      /tikz/draw=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/background color},
      /tikz/arrows=-,
      /tikz/line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/crossing over clearance}}}
```

I have separated out the color specification from the draw option.

Comment: I didn't test it but I think if you expand the value, `/tikz/draw/expanded` it should also work.

Comment: @percusse I presume you mean `/tikz/draw/.expanded`.  If so, unfortunately that does not work.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Oh OK. Thank you though

Comment: In version 0.9 the error is not yet existing. But If I use your and the original version of `crossing over`, there is no change visible. I do not know if Mr. Neves has changed something or if the bug was somewhere else.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi This seems to be fixed in 0.9e.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes, clearly. But your code has not been taken for this. So I wonder if the problem was lying somewhere else... but doesn't matter.