# Arrow tip size issue

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd

I have been playing around with tikz-cd for quite a while and I love it, except when it comes to 3d-cubic diagrams. I have not found a viable solution so far and all the solutions out there seem to have an issue. The one that came closest to solving my problem was this one :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

$$
\begin{tikzcd}
S'Sc \ar{rr}{} \ar{rd}{} \ar{dd}{}  &                                               & T'Sc \ar{rd}{} \ar{dd}{}  &                   \\
                                    & S'Sc' \ar[crossing over]{rr}{}                &                           & T'Sc \ar{dd}{}    \\
S'Tc \ar{rr}{} \ar{rd}{}            &                                               & T'Tc \ar{rd}{}            &                   \\
                                    & S'Tc' \ar{rr}{} \ar[<-,crossing over]{uu}{}   &                           & T'Tc          
\end{tikzcd}
$$
\end{document}
```

but in the output, the arrow shown by `\ar[<-,crossing over]` has a smaller arrow tip than my other arrows; this issue seems to be caused by `<-` (the point is to reverse its direction).

What is the issue with the commands `->` and `<-` which makes the arrow tip they generate smaller than the other ones?

Comment: Maybe the answer of this post can help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169512/tikz-style-arrow-tips-missing-when-using-tikz-cd-crossing-over

Comment: You should update your `tikz-cd` to version 0.9. This has been fixed already. Do you have the same issue when using the `from=uu` syntax as I do in my cube-answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234151

Comment: By the way, check [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) about your usage of `$$`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi : from=uu doesn't even compile. To be honest I have installed tikz-cd so long ago I didn't even know there was an update!